# Unable to autowire SessionFactory in My DAO Class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am tring to autowire a sessionfactory for my dao class but its not working

here is my context xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.spring.web.data">
    </context:component-scan>

    <beans profile="dev">


        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">

            <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"></property>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:Databases/testdb;create=true"></property>
            <property name="password" value=""></property>
            <property name="username" value=""></property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
            <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>com.test.spring.web.dao</value>
                    <!-- <value>com.test.spring.web.service</value>
                    <value>com.test.spring.web.controllers</value> -->
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        </bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven />

    </beans>


</beans>
```

my dao class

```
package com.test.spring.web.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Transactional
@Component("usersDao")
public class UsersDAO {



    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Autowired
    public Session session(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    }


     public void create(User user) {


         session().save(user);

    }

}
```

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.spring.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>webtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.10.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have a todoservice service class which autowire users dao class but anyway its always giving me following error

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'toDoService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.test.spring.web.service.ToDoService.setUsersDAO(com.test.spring.web.dao.UsersDAO); nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session

this is my service class as well

```
package com.test.spring.web.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.test.spring.web.dao.User;
import com.test.spring.web.dao.UsersDAO;

@Service("toDoService")
public class ToDoService {

    private UsersDAO usersDao;

    public UsersDAO getUsersDAO() {
        return usersDao;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUsersDAO(UsersDAO usersDAO) {
        this.usersDao = usersDAO;
    }

    public void create(User user) {
        usersDao.create(user);

    }

}
```

Please provide a little help on this.I have wasted whole day to find a solution for this. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't fit it in a comment, but why do you have a dependency on:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

What happens when you remove it?

Answer (score 0):

seems its a jar issue.Remove

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
<version>3.5.4-Final</version>
<type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

And also where you have define service package name in context:component-scan

I have removed the dependency but its still not working. I have added service package under a different xml name name service-context.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.spring.web.service">
    </context:component-scan>


</beans>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session, It means org.hibernate.Session is not found in the WEB-INF\lib. Make sure that WEB-INF\lib of the WAR contains all the required jars.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this,

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```